# Define role for both Http and websocket API in one serverlss.yml

Tags: lambda, serverless-framework

I am using AWS Websocket API with serverless framework 1.38.0 and I want to deploy both http and websocket event lamda with single serverless.yml and with one existing IAM role. Hence for this I have declared role arn in provider tab but when I run `sls deploy -v` it says `error - cannot read properties undefined`.

My understanding is we can only define role arn at function level either for event type `http` or `wss` or vice versa.

Please help me how to define EXISTING role for both API’s either at global level or function level, sample YAML configuration will really help.

My Sample YAML:

```
hello:
  handler: CsharpHandlers::AwsDotnetCsharp.Handler::Hello
  role: arn:aws:iam::019095984934:role/LambdaDeployment
  name: APITypeHello
  events:
    - http:
        path: api/shipments
        method: post
        cors: true
chatMessage:
  handler: CsharpHandlers::AwsDotnetCsharp.WebsocketHandler::GetWSSRequest
  #role: arn:aws:iam::019095984934:role/websocketTesting-dev-ap-southeast-1-lambdaRole - below is the custom admin role
  #role: arn:aws:iam::019095984934:role/LambdaDeployment
  name: chatMessage
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction,
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: “arn:aws:lambda:::function:*”
```

Thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 0):

You can set `role` and `iamRoleStatements` on the `provider` level to apply custom roles and role statements to all functions within your service.

e.g.

```
provider:
  role: arn:aws:iam::019095984934:role/LambdaDeployment
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: Allow
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction,
        - lambda:InvokeAsync
      Resource: “arn:aws:lambda:::function:*”

functions:
  hello:
    # ...
  chatMessage:
    # ...
```

Provider settings will be applied to both `hello` and `chatMessage` functions.

I advise you stick to setting `iamRoleStatements` at the `provider` level and only use `role` if you have to use a pre-existing role outside your serverless deployment.

Check the [IAM documentation](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but as i said i have 2 type of http end points one for websocket and one for http hence it not allowing us to define role at provider level. We are using serverless 1.38.0

Comment: @AnkurGupta If you want to give different rules to different Lambdas you still can do that at a provider level, just specify the function via the Resource attribute.